# Adding non-condensable gasses to a steam header

Tags: gas, condensation

I was asked today if non-condensable gases were introduced into a pipeline would it affect the condensing temperature of the steam.

For example 0.5 bar steam's saturation temperature is 81.3C if I had no other gases present in the system.  But if NCGs are introduced such that steam is now only 90% of the vapor, its partial pressure has now decreased to 0.45 bar assuming the total pressure is being regulated to 0.5bar.  Won't this affect the saturated vapor temperature?  If not why?